# Relations of correlation function and structure function in fluid mechanics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence

This [paper](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2021EA002201) (LINDBORG, 2007, DOI:10.1175/JAS3864.1) involves 3 correlation functions and 1 structure function, as defined below:
$$
R_{ij}(\mathbf x, \mathbf r) = 
\langle u_i(\mathbf x) u_j(\mathbf x + \mathbf r) \rangle 
$$

$$
Q_{ij}(\mathbf x, \mathbf r) =
\langle \xi_i(\mathbf x) \xi_j(\mathbf x + \mathbf r) \rangle
$$

$$
D_{ij}(\mathbf x, \mathbf r) = 
\langle \delta u_i \delta u_j \rangle
$$

$$
P(\mathbf x, \mathbf r) =
\langle \nabla_h \cdot \mathbf u_h(\mathbf x + \mathbf r) 
\nabla_h \cdot \mathbf u_h(\mathbf x) \rangle
$$
where where $\mathbf u$ is the fluctuating velocity field, and $\mathbf \xi$ is the
fluctuating vorticity field, $\delta u = \mathbf u(\mathbf x + \mathbf r) - 
\mathbf u(\mathbf x)$. Here $Q$ and $P$ are two-point correlation functions of
vertical vorticity and horizontal divergence. The subscripts $h$ denotes
horizontal and $\langle \cdots \rangle$ denotes an ensemble average or a time
average.

And two relations are given:
$$
Q_{zz}(x_3,\rho,z) = -\frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{1}{\rho} 
\frac{\partial D_{\rho\rho}}{\partial rho} - \frac{1}{\rho^2} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} \left( \rho^2 \frac
{\partial D_{\phi\phi}}{\partial \rho} \right) \right]
$$

$$
P(x_3,\rho,z) = - \nabla^2_h (R_{\rho\rho} + R_{\phi\phi}) - Q_{zz}
$$

I cannot figure out how to derive these two relations.